# FetchXML Query is not working in liquid templates

Tags: liquid, fetchxml, adxstudio-portals

I have below fetchxml query that is running fine in Advanced Find / FetchXML Builder. However, in liquid templates, same query is returning nothing.

```js
{% fetchxml feed %}
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="contact">
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <attribute name="telephone1" />
    <attribute name="contactid" />
    <order attribute="fullname" descending="false" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
{% endfetchxml %}
{
    "results":[
        {% for item in feed.results.entities %}
        {
            "Id":"{{ item.ebecs_vatgroupid }}",
            "Name":"{{ item.ebecs_name }}"
        }{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
        {% endfor %}
    ]
}
```

I'm system admin and have due entity permissions as well as well web roles associated to my user. Can anyone please assist in this regard?

***UPDATE***
Here is the output in the browser. It is returning liquid tags as is.
[image]

Comment: I think this could be a mistake while you copy pasted here. But cross check the code, as you don’t have ‘ebecs_vatgroupid’ in select column list.

Comment: Hi @ArunVinoth, yes it was the issue with the code. But not the one you highlighted. It was with liquid tags. There was hidden white space between { and % I removed and got the same working.

Comment: @AliMohsin you should write this as an answer so that the question can be closed